# Unity custom editor create new mesh if values change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, mesh, unity-editor

I have a script that inherits from **Graphics class** to draw a mesh. I created a **custom editor script** (see example below) it. However, when values get changed in the custom editor, **OnPopulateMesh is not called**, but without the custom editor the mesh was always drawn new when the variables changed. How can I trigger the mesh script to create a new one and achieve the same behaviour as before?

This is how my custom editor script looks like:

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    MeshScript ms = (MeshScript) target;

    ms.positionType = (MeshScript.PositionType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Positioning", ms.positionType);

    if (ms.positionType == MeshScript.PositionType.RectTransform)
    {
        ms.point1Transform = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Transform 1", ms.point1Transform, typeof(RectTransform), true) as RectTransform;
        ms.point2Transform = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Transform 2", ms.point2Transform, typeof(RectTransform), true) as RectTransform;
    }
    else if(ms.positionType == MeshScript.PositionType.Vector)
    {
        ms.point1Vector = EditorGUILayout.Vector2Field("Vector 1", ms.point1Vector);
        ms.point2Vector = EditorGUILayout.Vector2Field("Vector 2", ms.point2Vector);
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me, thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you could share the code for the custom editor so we can see what you're actually doing...

Comment: @RetiredNinja Well, in there i am just setting the variables of the target variable directly to a FloatField for example in OnInspectorGUI(). I will add some examples to the question.

Comment: Which variable are you interested in change tracking?  There is no mesh variable shown in your code, but that seems to be what you are interested in.

Comment: @hijinxbassist Sorry, I think there was a misunderstanding. The script "MeshScript" inherits from Graphic and creates a Mesh by calculating the vertices and triangles etc., which happens through OnPopulateMesh. And I want to trigger that method whenever a variable in the custom editor has changed, but it is protected. I hope it is more clear now. Thanks for your answer!